# Detect "using" within "using"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, nested, using

I'm working on a C# application, which is regularly using the following piece of source code:

```
using (var database ...
```

I'm facing a problem (an exception has been thrown) and I'm afraid it might be caused by a `using` clause, being called within another `using` clause (**on the same variable**: I don't care about nested `using` clauses on different variables).

Is there a way to detect this, using Visual Studio debugger?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nested using statements are almost always fine. Detecting it would almost always be a bad idea. Rather than reaching directly for detection in VS, I'd suggest spending your time on the *specific* problem you're facing.

Comment: `using` within `using` is quite OK: `using (var dataBase = new SqlConnection(...)) { ... using (var q = new SqlCommand(...)) {  ... using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {...} } }`

Comment: What kind of exception do you have (type and message)? Could you provide *relevant code*, please?

Comment: I'm not afraid about `using variable` within `using another_variable`, but `using database` within `using database`, causing the scope of that same `database` to be doubtful.

Comment: It sounds like you have designed your application poorly if you might end up in that situation but I'm not sure why it would be an issue anyway. Each `using` statement should generally be creating a new object anyway, so you'd still be disposing different objects at the end of each block. Why would that be an issue?

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I'm dealing with one part of the application that accesses an object within database, while it seems not to be present, and I'm wondering if a nested `using database` clause might cause this.

Comment: There's no way for VS to specifically detect nested `using` statements but you can always use the *Find in Files* tool. That supports regular expressions so you should be able to find what you're looking for even if you have been inconsistent with your variable names.

Comment: You mean you have multiple connections nested looking on the same database? Then you should rather look at your handling of transactions and what can be seen by what connection if you have objects in limbo and have problems finding them in the db.

Comment: @JonSkeet - if the connetion pool limit of database was reached could a nested database connection be a problem - as the inner connection fiddles around with the underlying connection of the outer database connection?

Comment: @RandRandom: I'm sure there are exceptions to the rule, but not enough to make it useful to have a general VS detector. Unfortunately this question isn't really clear IMO.

Comment: The docs say: "If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: What kind of exception? If the exception is thrown from the Dispose method, that is a bug, you should report it to the author. The [Dispose Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) requires that exceptions should not be thrown from within Dispose.

Comment: @Ralf: I'm working with SQL-Server. Can this cause a problem?

Comment: Sure but as we don't know much it can still be almost anything. You still haven't told what Exception you actually get. What does actually "same variable" mean here? I can just assume its not the same variable but a different variable with the same name. If not show more code that actually has a `using(database)` without the var in it that shows reusing the variable.

Comment: @Ralf: the error I get is that an entry is not present while I expect it to be.

Comment: That sound a lot like transaction isolation maybe part of the problem. Presumably you should create a new question as this one has definitely gone the wrong direction. Show some code there at least showing how you handle transactions (if you do explicitly) and should show how you create connections (we need to see the connection string). If possible show "how" they are nested and what the individual connections execute on the database.

Comment: @Ralf: I'll have a look for this tomorrow. Thanks for the support until now.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely `using` can cause issues. Only exception that I can think of that `using` might cause is `ObjectDisposedException`, which throws if an operation is performed on a disposed object.
If you are getting a different exception, probably it's not related to `using`.

For debugging purposes you can comment out all the using statements and try if that exception still happens.

If there is any issue with disposing items before finish using them, you can add those related items under one using block. So, they all will be disposed together.

Eg:

```
using (var db = new Database())
using (var con= new DBCon())
{
    
}
```

Comment: Yeah, not really - `class Foo { bool IsClosed => IsDisposed ? throw new MyFancyExcption() : false; }`

Comment: @RandRandom Yeah true, that's possible if someone tried a Fancy Exception. At least that FancyException should derived from ObjectDisposedException?
Anyway, I agree, I'll correct my wording. Thanks

Comment: `Dispose()` is not *supposed* to throw even if called multiple times, there are bad implementations though

Comment: @Charlieface Sure, Calling Dispose multiple time wouldn't throw an exception in the Dispose method. What I meant was, if it try using an object that's already disposed, it can cause issues.